# Magento2: How to show product video in Video tag insted of iframe

Tags: magento2, product-video

I need to show product youtube video in html Video tag. For example like [this](https://www.everlane.com/products/womens-square-silk-shirt-palepink?collection=womens-tops)

Can someone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do things :

1. Host all video and player assets remotely and paste in code almost anywhere (blocks, widgets) JW Player and SlideShowPro both work on web and iOS now
2. For pure HTML5 video tag just paste in the code (all URLs absolute and outside of Magento)

Comment: I have product video added in backend and need to use that video in html video tag. How to do that?

Comment: Try this -
simply render that block and template in detail tab

Add the below line in <magento-root>/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme_name/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml before end of div tag

<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery")->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/view/gallery.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>

The output is look like below may be your styling get different because I do some LESS work for my image view. 
OR Refer this
www.demagento.com/how-to-add-magento-product-video-programmatically/

Comment: Magento default template using iframe to display video but I need to replace video tag.